# Flutter Firestore snapshot is returning data but Firestore Database is empty

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

My Flutter application was reading from and writing to Firestore successfully but suddenly stopped working.  When I call the following method the plan data is printed:

```
Future<void> readCurrentPlan() async {
    final path = APIPath.plansT(uid);
    final reference = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(path);
    final snapshots = reference.snapshots();
    snapshots.listen((snapshot) {
      snapshot.docs.forEach((snapshot) {
        print(snapshot.data());
      });
    });
  }
  # Prints: {isComplete: false, planId: TEST, finalMaxPull: 200, initialMax: 100}
```

However when I go to my Firestore in my Firebase console there is no data in my database.  I know I am checking in the correct application's database as I can see my login to my application under the Authentication tab.  Additionally, when I call the following method, the `await` portion of the function never completes:

```
Future<void> setTrainingPlan(PlanT plan) async {
    final planPath = APIPath.plan(uid, plan.planId);
    final planDocumentReference = FirebaseFirestore.instance.doc(planPath);
    await planDocumentReference.set(plan.toMap());
}
```

Where is `readCurrentPlan()` getting `snapshot.data()` from and does this explain why am I suddenly unable to write to Firestore?

Comment: Firestore [caches data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline) locally. Could the data be coming from the local cache that you run the app on?

Comment: You got it, thanks! After setting `persistenceEnabled: false` I stopped getting any snapshot data from `readCurrentPlan()`. I still do not know why I am unable to write to Firestore anymore but this gave me some much needed progress.